# Cascading Referential integrity

Tags: sql-server

I'm using `Employee`, `City`, `EmpSalary`, `EmpOrganization`, `Salcomponents` tables in my database where `Employee` table `CityID` column references `CityID` of `City` table, and reporting ID column self references `EmpID` of `Employee` table

- `Empsalary` table `empId` references `Employee.EmpId`
- `EmpOrganization` table `empid` references `Employee.EmpId`

I want to design a stored procedure with `CityId` as input to delete data from `Employee`, `Empsalary`, `Emporganization` simultaneously

Please suggest how to proceed further?

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help us to understand better between did you try anything ?

Comment: You don't need to write anything. Change your FK definitions to enable Cascade Deletion and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stored proceudre. You can design your foregin key constraints that they cascade the delete:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CityId) REFERENCES City (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This will delete the entry in the City table when the Employee entry is deleted.

Comment: thank you Sefe , but I have already done so , I don't want to delete data from master table i.e from city and salcomponents ,the data should be deleted from  Employee,EmpSalary,EmpOrganization